# IntegrityError Insert or update on table "orders_order" violates foreign key constraint "

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, foreign-keys

I am trying to build an ecommerce site in Django 1.7 everything works except when I try to use the checkout, I got the following error.  I am not sure wht it is doing this as it works fine on my localhost but not when I try to deploy on webfaction.
 Many thanks

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://myshoppingapp.com/checkout/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'accounts',
 'carts',
 'marketing',
 'orders',
 'products',
 'localflavor',
 'stripe')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'marketing.middleware.DisplayMarketing')


Traceback:
File "/home/jamessmith/webapps/myshoppingapp/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/jamessmith/webapps/myshoppingapp/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jamessmith/webapps/myshoppingapp/src/orders/views.py" in checkout
  55.       new_order.save()
File "/home/jamessmith/webapps/myshoppingapp/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  591.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/jamessmith/webapps/myshoppingapp/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  619.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/home/jamessmith/webapps/myshoppingapp/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/transaction.py" in __exit__
  339.                         connection.commit()
File "/home/jamessmith/webapps/myshoppingapp/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in commit
  176.         self._commit()
File "/home/jamessmith/webapps/myshoppingapp/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in _commit
  145.                 return self.connection.commit()
File "/home/jamessmith/webapps/myshoppingapp/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/jamessmith/webapps/myshoppingapp/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in _commit
  145.                 return self.connection.commit()

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /checkout/
Exception Value: insert or update on table "orders_order" violates foreign key constraint "billing_address_id_41625ebca5013523_fk_accounts_useraddress_id"
DETAIL:  Key (billing_address_id)=(1) is not present in table "accounts_useraddress".
```

Answer (score 13):

The important detail is in this line:

```
DETAIL:  Key (billing_address_id)=(1) is not present in table "accounts_useraddress".
```

The problem is that you are trying to link an order with a billing address which is not yet present in the database.

In your code you'll need to make sure that the billing address is saved to the database before you try and save an object that is related to it by foreign key.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to how to do this?  I'm trying I feel very stupid :-(

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code from your views.py file where you are doing new_order.save()?