# Django IntegrityError changing a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I have a model `LucyGuide` which extends Django's `User` model through a `OneToOneField`:

```
class LucyGuide(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

There is also a `Company` model which has a field called `lucy_guide` which is a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    lucy_guide = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I'd like to change this to

```
class Company(models.Model):
    lucy_guide = models.ForeignKey(LucyGuide)
```

However, when I implement this change and make and run migrations, I run into an `IntegrityError`:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "lucy_web_company" violates foreign key constraint "lucy_web_company_lucy_guide_id_de643702_fk_lucy_web_"
DETAIL:  Key (lucy_guide_id)=(461) is not present in table "lucy_web_lucyguide".
```

This question is similar to [IntegrityError Insert or update on table "orders_order" violates foreign key constraint "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658491/integrityerror-insert-or-update-on-table-orders-order-violates-foreign-key-con); it seems like I have created `LucyGuide` objects before referencing them as foreign keys.

What is the best way to fix this? Is there a series of commands I need to write in the shell to create these users?

**Update**

From looking around in the shell, it seems like Django still expects the same numerical `id`s for the `ForeignKey`, even though the model has changed (from `User` to `LucyGuide`). Here are the `ids` of `User`s which are also `LucyGuide`s:

```
In [11]: lucy_guide_users = [user for user in User.objects.all() if hasattr(user, 'lucyguide')]

In [16]: [user.id for user in lucy_guide_users]
Out[16]: [12, 8, 461, 497, 500, 471, 475, 495]
```

Notice that this contains the `id` of `461` from the error. The `id`s of `LucyGuide`s, however, are simply

```
In [17]: [guide.id for guide in LucyGuide.objects.all()]
Out[17]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

It seems like the way to fix this is to change the primary keys of the `LucyGuide`s, but it seems from [What is the best approach to change primary keys in an existing Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055784/what-is-the-best-approach-to-change-primary-keys-in-an-existing-django-app) that this is a very involved process. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You shouldn't try to change the primary keys of the objects in the `LucyGuide` table. Instead you want to change the `lucy_guide_id` values in the `Company` table so that they reference `LucyGuide` rows. Unfortunately, that's quite an involved process. The [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055784/what-is-the-best-approach-to-change-primary-keys-in-an-existing-django-app) to is about changing the field type of a primary key (e.g. from a `CharField` to `AutoField`), which is a different problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't simply change the target of the foreign key. For each existing company, you need to change `lucy_guide_id` from the related user's id to the related lucy_guide's id. Django can't do this for you.

You could do the migration in several steps. First, add a new foreign key and create a migration

```
class Company(models.Model):
    lucy_guide = models.ForeignKey(User)
    new_lucy_guide = models.ForeignKey(LucyGuide, blank=True, null=True)
```

Next, create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to populate the `new_lucy_guide` field.

Then you can drop the `lucy_guide` field, and create a migration.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    new_lucy_guide = models.ForeignKey(LucyGuide, blank=True, null=True)
```

Finally you can rename your field and create a migration:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    lucy_guide = models.ForeignKey(LucyGuide, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Just as a precision: you can't do the last two steps at once. It will see the new field as `RemoveField` and consider the name change as `AlterField` on the old one.

Comment: @PierreMonico thanks for confirming. I've removed the paragraph that suggests you might be combine the last two steps in one migration.

Comment: The only way to do it would be to edit the migration file manually.