# Django: Integrity error installing fixtures

Tags: django, django-models, heroku-postgres

**Foreground**

Hi. I´m uploading my Django app database to my Heroku production environment. When I try to `manage.py loaddata` I get the following error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: insert or update in table "catalog_contactos" violates key constraint.

I found this post where someone suggests that first you should load models that are the base for foreign key: [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658491/integrityerror-insert-or-update-on-table-orders-order-violates-foreign-key-con/30658538)

Also I found this post that refers to moving a database to another app (the production version for example). Basically it says:

> When you backup whole database by using dumpdata command, it will
>   backup all the database tables
>
> If you use this database dump to load the fresh database(in another
>   django project), it can be causes IntegrityError (If you loaddata in
>   same database it works fine)
>
> To fix this problem, make sure to backup the database by excluding
>   contenttypes and auth.permissions tables

[Link to the post](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata)

**My code**

Following that suggestions I do:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > data.json
```

Then on the server I run the following code and get the integrity error:

```
heroku run python manage.py loaddata data.json
```

Should I `dumpdata` model by model and `loaddata` them in a certaing order? Or I´m coding something wrong? Any clues?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Could this "Natural keys" issue be the solutuion? [Django serializing objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/#natural-keys)

Answer (score 0):

When I had integrity error with django/postgreSQL I did DROP TABLE table in postgreSQL.